# What's the default boot parameter for CentOS 6.2?

Tags: centos, grub2

I forgot to install a boot loader during LiveCD installation , since i've got other distribution resides in my system , i could add another entry into grub2 , but what's the default parameter for CentOS ?

```
  linux /vmlinuz-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 root=//dev/XX ??
  initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.img
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the default `grub.conf` for CentOS 6.2. Check what you need and append to your grub.conf per your requirements.

```
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=2fff651e-8708-446c-8d9a-ec448636485f rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup00/LogVol01 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM
initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.img
title Other
rootnoverify (hd1,0)
chainloader +1
```